# Airflow Xcom: split the string and store each splitted variable into a new variable

Tags: jinja2, airflow

In Airflow GUI can see that my xcom variable looks like `['val1', 'val2', 'val3']`. If I have understood it correctly from the documentation, when I do `{{ ti.xcom_pull("task_id") }}` will be a string. So my question is how do I split the xcom varible so that I get three seperate values wihch I will then use later in my other task?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have a string representation of list `"['val1', 'val2', 'val3']"` and you want to convert it into a list object: `['val1', 'val2', 'val3']` so you can do it in any string to list manipulation that you prefer.

However, Airflow has a better option. You can set     `render_template_as_native_obj=True` :

```
dag = DAG(
    ...
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
```

by setting `render_template_as_native_obj=True` Airflow uses Jinja’s [NativeEnvironment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/nativetypes/), which allows rendering a template produces a native Python type. You can read about it in this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects).

Comment: I don't think this work in my Airflow, I'm using Airflow 1.10.2

Comment: So you must use the first option. You can write a macro that reads the xcom and return the value as list.